# Cordova Barcodescanner : Error - write settings : false

Tags: android, cordova, dojo, cordova-plugins

I am trying to integrate corodova barcode scanner with Dojo Mobile.

Barcode scanner : https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-barcodescanner

However when i try to scan I am getting **write settings : false**

Could someone help me on this ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How did you fix this issue? I am also facing it. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and was able to fix it by changing target-sdk to 20

Answer (score 0):

You may find more help here:

https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner/issues/139

The problem seems to be that the barcode-scanner (still) does not request the camera permissions. The workarounds are:

- Request the permissions before
- Allow Camera in Settings/App